# How to call a function with arguments, return from the function and assign what was returned to a variable?

Tags: function, vba, excel

This is what I was trying:

Calling the function from the module:

```
LastWorkingDay = IsBusinessDay(Yesterday)
```

Function:

```
Public Function IsBusinessDay(Yesterday As Variant) As Date

...

InterestingVariable = #20/02/2014#

End Function
```

I would like to return InterestingVariable and assign it to LastWorkingDay. There is no return statement in VBA, so how do you decide what you want to return. Or, how do you call a function to return a particular variable calculated in the function In my case it would "InterestingVariable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` in VBA is the **function name** and = `<return value>`

so for example

```
Public Function MyFunction() as String
    MyFunction = "returned from MyFunction"
End Function
```

so `MsgBox MyFunction` returns a `String`  *returned from MyFunction*

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your function

```
IsBusinessDay = InterestingVariable
```